# Why Lenovo smartphone fails to support USB OTG?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, lenovo

alike questions:

1. [OTG support in Android Smartphones](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128361/otg-support-in-android-smartphones)
2. [Connecting Android smartphone/tablet to PC and another device through USB hub](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19869/connecting-android-smartphone-tablet-to-pc-and-another-device-through-usb-hub)
3. [How Does Android Detect USB Connectivity and More About USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144107/how-does-android-detect-usb-connectivity-and-more-about-usb)

"Most tablets seem to supply power over USB, but many phones do NOT.

Exactly.
I tried to connect my smartphone to tablet to get ADB to work.
Unfortunately my smartphone (Lenovo) failed to recognize connected tablet as a device.

My friend adviced me basic test if OTG is supported on smartphone.

Connecting usb mouse via OTG cable to smartphone works on tablets but fails on my smartphone ( red laser led is down)

There are apps in Android store and OTG USB Driver For Android
claims after check:

This Device Supports USB On-The-Go (OTG) (my Lenovo)

and other OTG Checker app claims quite the opposite

and one another advices me to edit xml file to enable OTG

I will run another test, powering the device/s with powered USB hub as a middle-man,
since tested today USB Endoscope camera and installed a number of camera apps and none worked for me, especially AN98 advised by a manufacturer of Encoscope 1m usb camera.

At the same time I can connect my Lenovo smartphone to PC via usb cable to get connection established confirmation for files transfer.

follow-up 2

I give up usb hub connection option, as discussed already in

[Connecting Android smartphone/tablet to PC and another device through USB hub](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19869/connecting-android-smartphone-tablet-to-pc-and-another-device-through-usb-hub?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Since I have Terminal Emulator installed
I can run
adb usb
to get :
daemon not running, starting it now on port 5038
daemon started successfully
error: device not found

Not sure why port assigned is: 5038

should be : 5555 by default

nice option is
Name of adb server host (default: localhost)
-P  Port of adb server ( default: 5037)

Comment: USB OTG is mostly used with USB sticks, mouse and keyboard. Besides those devices no device developer will ever test. ADB was never meant to be run over USB OTG. Therefore I am not sure if Android even includes the necessary drivers. My advaice if you still want a Android device-to-device communication via USB: Use a Raspberry PI as PC (SUB master) in between both devices and develop a script that runs on the Raspberry that receives ADB commands from one device and forwards them to the other.

Comment: @Robert I use USB OTG cable as USB female > microUSB adapter only since none microUSB <> microUSB cable offered for sale. Today purchased a number of USB female > type-C adapters for use in a future (since my Lenovo smartphone supports microUSB only). It looks like if a smartphone doesn't support OTG so is not fit for ADB communication.
Ok, I need to run ADB on the same smartphone (null USB port) either daemon or client to limit overheads. Just go back to ADB manual on how to.  I need ADB client for Android

Comment: check your phone specifications